# Bug with posting comments

Tags: bug, comments

I just managed to post a comment twice for some reason. It's in: [Is there a Macgyver-esque way to charge rechargeable batteries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38114/is-there-a-macgyver-esque-way-to-charge-rechargeable-batteries/38345?noredirect=1#comment69036_38345)

I know I can remove one of them, but I just thought that the SE team might have a look at how I managed (I didn't do anything strange, besides posting a minimum-length comment), because it may be a possible safety hole in the anti-comment-spam system.